# Appending text from the file to an output,printing to file C#

Tags: c#, append, filereader, streamreader

I am writing a command method that reads the contents of a txt file and has the correct checks if the filename is already used, if it exists, etc.

The only issue I am having is that after the file is read I cannot get it to write the contents of the file to append after a line of text I have in another text file.

I have it printing to the console correctly, but I also would like to append the text of the contents to the output I having writing to the file as well.

Any ideas? I know its a simple fix but none of my solutions will append the contents...

```
 protected void read(string command, string param1)
        {
            //read the contents of a created file
            // check if file exists
            // if it exists send message to console that file was found
            // let user know that the file exist, but is empty
            // if file does not exist, let the user know that the file does not exist

            //checks name of the file, if it exists, then reads and displays the contents of the file in console and in audit.txt
            if (param1 == "accounts.txt" || param1 == "audit.txt" || param1 == "groups.txt" || param1 == "files.txt")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot use this filename");
                Console.Read();
                return;
            }
            //checks if file exists
            //if it doesnt exist program should terminate
            else if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Files\"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Filename doesnt exist");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //checks if the file exists and reads the contents of the file
                string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Files\", param1);
                using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                    string line = null;
                    do
                    {
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        Console.Read();
                    } while (line != null);
                }
                string path2 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
                {
                    sw2.WriteLine("User read " + param1 + " as: (should display contents of the file)""); //apend the text from the file into the audit log, and name from current login
                }
                Console.Read();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: So you want to append the contents of the file in `path` at the end of the file in `path2`?

Comment: yes correct, after it reads the contents of the path in path1 it needs to display those contents in the path2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path1))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(path2))
    {
        writer.Write("User read " + param1 + " as: ");

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            //Console.WriteLine(line); //Uncomment this line if you want to write the line to the console

            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would do something like this instead of the last part where I write to path2?

Comment: You should merge the two `using` sections in the `else` part of your code into something like the code I provided.

Comment: but how would it append the text to string?:
sw2.WriteLine("User read " + param1 + " as: (contents of the file)"");

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of input file and the value of `param1` and the expected output?

Comment: Say we have a filename called "testing.txt". param1 is the name of the file in the C drive "testing.txt"
We are reading in text that is contained in testing.txt, for example "this is a test" is the text in the txt file.

The correct output would be:

"User read testing.txt as: this is a test"

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot more sense